# Null check in the return statement

Tags: javascript, return, angular7

When I have a null value in `data.req`, `data.req.toLowerCase()` is throwing an error. How can I check for a condition like

```
if(data.req === null) {
    //do nothing
} else { 
    data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1
}
```

// How should i check for null for only data.req in the below mentioned return statement ?

```
return data.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.client) !== -1
    && data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1;
```

// sample data

```
Data: [{req: "test", client: "client_01"},
{req: "now_test_01", client: "sample client"},
{req: "test", client: "client_01"},
{req: null, client: "sample client"},
{req: null, client: "client_01"},
{req: "now_test_018", client: "sample client"}]
```

Comment: Add a `&& data.req` check

Comment: you also can cast null to empty string, (data.req + '').toLowerCase() if you like

Comment: @ClancyHood `null + ''` returns `"null"`

Comment: dang, I need to revisit my wat lecture https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Here am doing a filter on the table data

Comment: filterRequests(): (data: any, filter: string) => boolean {
    const filterFunction = function (data, filter): boolean {
      const searchTerms = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.client) !== -1
        data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1 ;
    };
    return filterFunction;
  }

Comment: Please also add a few examples of searches on the sample data and what they should return.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a default value, if the `data.req` is `null`.

```
(data.req || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1
```

Or with ES6

```
(data.req || '').toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.req)
```

Comment: please add some examples of what you have and what you like to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do following:

```
return !searchTerm.req || data.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.client) !== -1
    && data.req && data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1;
```

Comment: if i do this the filter function is filtering the data which has null value, but i should show the data which has null value

Comment: Do you want to show **only** the null values or both?

Comment: When i don't have any value in searchTerms.req i have to show both, but when i have some value in searchTerms.req i have to show the data which contains searchTerms.req in data.req

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it's right, because I still don't understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return data.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.client) !== -1
   && ((data.req == null && (searchTerms.req == null || searchTerms.req == "")) 
      || (data.req && data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1));
```

Comment: No this is not working when the searchTerms.req has the value, when searchTerms.req = 'test' it is returning true for data.req = null, which is wrong

Comment: (data.req == null || data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1)

Comment: The above mentioned condition is working when searchTerms.req = '', but not when there is some value in searchTerms.req. The condition that i am looking for is when searchTerms.req='tes' it has to return the data (mentioned in the quesion) with index numbers 0,1,2 & 5 but not 3 & 4.

Comment: @Abdulah - The solution which you gave is returning the records which has null values along with the filtered records

Answer (score 0):

Need to return the value based on condition, issue is resolved. I found the solution. Thanks everyone for your efforts.

```
return data.client.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.client) !== -1 
&& (searchTerms.req ? data.req && data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1 : 
(data.req == null || data.req.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.req) !== -1));
```

// This is for who has de-reputed this question: If possible try to give a solution when someone is merely looking for it.